# Python Tkinter postscript wrong size export

Tags: python, image, tkinter, postscript, turtle-graphics

Im using python turtle (Tkinter) to draw some lines which I need to export to a .jpg or .png file. To do so, I'm using python's turtle method to export my canvas to a postscript file:

`pen.getcanvas().postscript(file="grafica.ps")`

Where `pen` is just a fancy name for my turtle.

I get my .ps file, I convert it and... surprize! The image gets cut.

I tried some modifications like:

`pen.getcanvas().postscript(file="grafica.ps", colormode='color', pagewidth=1600, pageheight=1200, width=1600, height=1200)`

Since my turtle's window is 800x600 I thought that maybe twice as much space would be enough space to fit all the image but it still gets cut down...

I'm posting some output examples after the convertion, how my turtle's screen looks like when saving it, and how it should look exported.

`Window while saving the image:`
[image] (Yes, there are sliders for the canvas)

`How should it look:`
[image]

`And this is what I get:`[image]

I'm wondering how should I call postscript(), any idea?

I don't want to code this again on WxPython or other library :(

thanks!

Comment: This may be a postscript bounding box issue. Open the ps file in a text editor and look for the line `%%BoundingBox: xmin ymin xmax ymax` then increase the size of the box and check again. Hope it helps!

Comment: @darthbith Changed the values to `%%BoundingBox: -100000 -100000 100000 100000` but got exactly the same picture as shown above :(

Comment: Did you run `postscript()` again, or just try to view the file again? If you ran `postscript()` again, then you would overwrite the changed values of `%%BoundingBox` and get the same result. You should just view the image after changing the bounding box (sorry if you did that, I just want to make sure :-))

Comment: Can you put your resulting postscript file online somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer. I tried to view it again without generating a new .ps file.

Here you can see the .ps file: [Source](http://pastebin.com/jeDaF1wM)

I found something strange... I just got home, got the .ps file open with evice and it shows it perfectly.. Maybe my converting tool (Imagemagick) is not working?

Comment: Edit: Not working... try uploading the .ps [here](http://view.samurajdata.se/)

Comment: Its an EPS file, not a PostScript program. As such it doesn't request a media size, some interpreters will read the BoundingBox comments, some won't. Ghostscript (as used by ImageMagick) needs to be told that you want to honour the EPS BBox, so you need to specify -dEPSCrop

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider My typical workflow for .eps files on Windows may be slightly convoluted, but it works. Similar thing should work for Linux. Install GhostScript (http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), then use the `ps2pdf` utility from the command line with the `-dEPSCrop` option, so `pd2pdf -dEPSCrop input.eps output.pdf`. Then, I use ImageMagick to convert the PDF to anything else, e.g. png - `convert output.pdf output.png`. You can control the PNG resolution etc. through ImageMagick. Like I said, convoluted, but it works.

Comment: @darthbith This worked!! I don't know why but when converting to pdf the file appears as it should and then I can convert it to an image file without any problem, can you please leave your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem with ImageMagick interacting with the bounding box of the EPS file. My typical workflow for `.eps` files on Windows may be slightly convoluted, but it works. Similar thing should work for Linux. Install [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (you'll have to make sure the GhostScript executables are on your path), then use the `ps2pdf` utility from the command line with the `-dEPSCrop` option:

```
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop input.eps output.pdf.
```

Then, use ImageMagick to convert the PDF to anything else, e.g. PNG

```
convert output.pdf output.png
```

You can control the PNG resolution etc. through ImageMagick. Like I said, convoluted, but it works.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I needed. Just to add, it was important for me to set the  `-density` flag to 300% else after converting the pdf to png the image was blurry.

Thanks!